# Abaqus python scripting - Creating assembly level element set from elements of two parts

Tags: python, abaqus

I would like to create an assembly level set from two part sets using python scripting. Note that each part has a native mesh associated with it. Here is my attempt:

```
elsetPart1 = part1.Set(name='allElements', elements=part1.elements)
elsetPart2 = part2.Set(name='allElements', elements=part2.elements)

elsetAssembly = model.rootAssembly.Set('assemblyElements',
    elements=(elsetPart1.elements,elsetPart2.elements))

print(len(elsetPart1.elements), len(elsetPart2.elements),
len(elsetAssembly.elements))
```

Output: (3608, 2500, 0)

Why is this giving me zero elements in elsetAssembly, when there are clearly elements in each part?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in the above piece of code,

1. `elsetPart1` and `elsetPart2` are of `<type 'MeshElementArray'>` which could be concatenated with `+' rather than combining them as a tuple.
2. From my understanding `set Object` from part and assembly are different. So, access the `elsetPart1` from assembly.

   > elsetPart_a  = mdb.rootAssembly.instances[<part1>].sets[<elSetName>].elements
   >   elsetPart_b  = mdb.rootAssembly.instances[<part2>].sets[<elSetName>].elements
   >   elsetAssembly = model.rootAssembly.Set('assemblyElements',
   >   elements=elsetPart_a+elsetPart_b)